# C# 10 .Net 6 MinBy MaxBy Linq projection to single property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a inline way to project properties after the new `MinBy` or `MaxBy` calls in C# 10 .Net 6?

```
double topPriceInList = prices.MaxBy(h => h.High)."Select(h => h.High)";
```

Certainly Visual Studio 2021 doesn't like any that I have tried.

Comment: `MaxBy` and `MinBy` don't return `IEnumerable` - they return single elements. Just use `.High` at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MaxBy(this IEnumerable<T>)` and `MinBy(this IEnumerable<T>)` don't return `IEnumerable<T>` - they return single elements (i.e. `T`), so just do this:

```
double topPriceInList = prices.MaxBy(h => h.High).High;
```

That said, *that* code above doesn't need `MaxBy`, just use `Max`:

```
double topPriceInList = prices.Max(h => h.High);

// or:

double topPriceInList = prices.Select(h => h.High).Max();
```

---

- Note that `Min`, `Max`, `MinBy`, and `MaxBy` will all throw an exception at runtime if the source collection is empty (or any previous `.Where` steps eliminated all elements)
- ...so you may need to use `MinOrDefault`, `MaxOrDefault`, `MaxByOrDefault`, or `MaxByOrDefault`, in which case use the null-safe navigation operator `?.` (aka *elvis-operator*).

  - But make sure the `...OrDefault()` extension-method is invoked on `IEnumerable<Nullable<T>>` and *not* `IEnumerable<T>` because `default(T)` for value-types is never `null` which is a frequent source of bugs.

```
double? topPriceInListOrNull = prices.Select(h => (double?)h.High).MaxOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks I see my problem was that it was nullable so I had two problems.

Comment: @SuperDave What is the **exact type** of `prices`? Are you using value-tuples? Is it `Nullable<ValueTuple<double,...>>` or `Nullable<ValueTuple<Nullable<double>,...>` or `ValueTuple<Nullable<double>,...>`?

Comment: No tuples and yes IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @SuperDave So what is `T`, exactly?